# Error al iniciar Eclipse Oxygen Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-oxygen

*Resulta que venia utilizando el IDE eclipse sin problemas en Ubuntu 18, Luego de la actualización, creo que de Java, la aplicación no inicio mas. me dice que mire el .log y es el archivo se arroja esto...*

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-04-16 22:09:44.704
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 21 more
```

*Algunos foros dicen que tengo que colocar unas lineas en el .ini donde esta instalado eclipse, pero no da resultado. el .ini que tengo es esto...*

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
/home/cristian/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/


$java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

*Alguna idea, si ya les paso?*

Utilizo eclipse para desarrollar una aplciación en c++ para raspberry pi. cada vez que se me actualiza pasa algo, a veces es fasil de solucionar, otras veces tuve que reinstalar la aplicación, y a todo esto viene implicito la compilación cruzada y el debug del programa que con eclipse no lo puedo ejecutar correctamente, por el tema de los threads, si alguien tiene un tuto para debuguear remotamente con threads seria buenisimo.

Comment: Según revise, el problema parece ser en la versión de Eclipse con la de Java, trata de instalar la última versión de Eclipse.  ref. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1090046/

Comment: @ivanc no sera lo inverso? Su eclipse es del `2019-04-16` y su java de `2019-01-15`.

Comment: La solución fue volver a utilizar una versión de java anterior, Disculpen el tiempo que paso, no puedo chequear efectivamente cual es la versión pero creo que era la jdk-8.

Comment: La solución fue volver a utilizar una versión de java anterior, Disculpen el tiempo que paso, no puedo chequear efectivamente cual es la versión pero creo que era la jdk-8.